# How do I run only a subset of comparisons in a t.test using R?

Tags: r, t-test

I am using R to do some statistics:

I have generated a data.frame from raw data. The data includes a numeric variable (fold_change) and two factor variables (dis_status which includes RF and con, as well as glycan which includes 100 different glycans)

and it looks something like below with hundreds more glycans

```
 dis_status                      glycan fold_change
1           RF              Sulpho.Lewis.a  4.83433185
2           RF              Sulpho.Lewis.a  3.88519084
3          con              Sulpho.Lewis.a  0.94730194
4          con              Sulpho.Lewis.a  1.91278688
167         RF    P1.antigen.Trisaccharide  4.07173876
168         RF    P1.antigen.Trisaccharide  5.70383491
169        con    P1.antigen.Trisaccharide  1.34631723


> glimpse(stats_df)
Observations: 16,600
Variables: 3
$ dis_status  <fct> RF, RF, con, con, con, con, con, RF, RF, con, con, RF, con, con, RF, RF, RF, con, RF, con, RF, RF, RF, RF, RF, RF, con, RF, RF, con, con, con, RF, con, RF, RF,…
$ glycan      <fct> Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a, Sulpho.Lewis.a,…
$ fold_change <dbl> 4.83433185, 3.88519084, 0.94730194, 1.91278688, 6.94509886, 2.80368849, 0.78262431, 2.74972572, 4.37691596, 0.85835252, 1.25431865, 1.14603706, -1.82021891, 0.…
```

I run a t.test on the data:

```
ad_nonpaired <- pairwise.t.test(stats_df$fold_change,  stats_df$dis_status:stats_df$glycan, 
                               paired = F,
                               pool.sd = F,
                               p.adj = "none")
```

I will correct for multiple comparisons next but the issue I am having is this carries out t.tests between every possible combination of dis_status and glycan.

**I am only interested in the "RF" vs "con" for each individual glycan. So with the two glycans above, I only really want "Sulpho.Lewis.a" from "RF" compared to "Sulpho.Lewis.a" from "con" NOT any comparison between "P1.antigen.Trisaccharide" to "Sulpho.Lewis.a" but can not figure out how to specify this in the test?**

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/C/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] knitr_1.25          broom_0.5.2         ggrepel_0.8.1       readxl_1.3.1        forcats_0.4.0       stringr_1.4.0       dplyr_0.8.3         purrr_0.3.3        
 [9] readr_1.3.1         tidyr_1.0.0         tibble_2.1.3        ggplot2_3.2.1       tidyverse_1.2.1     limma_3.38.3        hexbin_1.27.3       vsn_3.50.0         
[17] Biobase_2.42.0      BiocGenerics_0.28.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2            lubridate_1.7.4       lattice_0.20-38       gtools_3.8.1          rprojroot_1.3-2       assertthat_0.2.1      zeallot_0.1.0         digest_0.6.22        
 [9] utf8_1.1.4            plyr_1.8.4            R6_2.4.0              cellranger_1.1.0      backports_1.1.5       evaluate_0.14         highr_0.8             httr_1.4.1           
[17] pillar_1.4.2          gplots_3.0.1.1        zlibbioc_1.28.0       rlang_0.4.1           lazyeval_0.2.2        curl_4.2              rstudioapi_0.10       gdata_2.18.0         
[25] preprocessCore_1.44.0 desc_1.2.0            labeling_0.3          splines_3.5.2         munsell_0.5.0         xfun_0.10             compiler_3.5.2        modelr_0.1.5         
[33] pkgconfig_2.0.3       tidyselect_0.2.5      fansi_0.4.0           crayon_1.3.4          withr_2.1.2           bitops_1.0-6          grid_3.5.2            nlme_3.1-141         
[41] jsonlite_1.6          gtable_0.3.0          lifecycle_0.1.0       affy_1.60.0           magrittr_1.5          scales_1.0.0          KernSmooth_2.23-16    cli_1.1.0            
[49] stringi_1.4.3         affyio_1.52.0         testthat_2.2.1        xml2_1.2.2            ellipsis_0.3.0        generics_0.0.2        vctrs_0.2.0           tools_3.5.2          
[57] glue_1.3.1            hms_0.5.2             pkgload_1.0.2         yaml_2.2.0            colorspace_1.4-1      BiocManager_1.30.9    caTools_1.17.1.2      rvest_0.3.4          
[65] haven_2.1.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just subset the data and then run the t.test on the resulting data frame, e.g. see the first answers here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/extract-a-subset-of-a-dataframe-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935479/how-to-combine-multiple-conditions-to-subset-a-data-frame-using-or

Comment: Yes, although this approach relies on the `pool.sd` option being `FALSE`. Otherwise sunsetting the data would change the variance estimate being used.  (Assuming I understand how the function works).